# Home directory file permissions screwed up, how do I "start over"?

Tags: permissions, rsync

I backed up my entire home directory using rsync and moved the backup to a new installation of Linux. Somehow my file permissions got completely screwed up (all files were owned by user "999" and file permissions were set to `777`).

I ran a quick `sudo chown -R username:username ~/` which [fixed some issues I was having with my audio](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388445/linux-mint-sound-does-not-work-after-restoring-home-folder), but now all my plain-text files (and even movies and music) are marked as executable, other users can view my files, etc.

How can I restore my file permissions to a "normal" state? Restoring from a backup isn't exactly possible, since the backup has screwed up permissions as well. I can always reinstall my OS and purge the config files from the backup, leaving me only with personal documents that I can then recursively set the permissions for, but what should I set the permissions to? A `sudo chmod -R 660 ~/Music` for example leaves me unable to listen to my music, even though I am the owner.

Comment: Do you still have the old files?

Comment: You want directories to be readable, writable and *executable* by you

Answer (score 9):

The following might help to clean up file and folder permissions quickly but will not fix anything that had different settings.

```
sudo chown -R <login>:<login> /home/<login>
find /home/<login> -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 664
find /home/<login> -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 775
```

`<login>` is of course your login. Change to `660` and `770` if you like.

There are a few special cases that require tighter permissions. This list is not complete by anyway but may help you get back up quickly.

Correction for Mail and ssh:

```
find /home/<login>/Mail -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 700
find /home/<login>/.ssh -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 700
find /home/<login>/Mail -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 600
find /home/<login>/.ssh -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 600
```

Note: Some files within `~/Mail` may need `640` or `644`. This will depend on your mail client.

Some other common files that would need the same permission as above are:

```
.gnome, .gnome2_private, .bash_history, .lesshst, .viminfo
```

**Edit:** Included `.ssh` info from Ulrich Schwarz's comment and expanded to include some more common directories and permissions. Also included the `chown -R` command that was already run by the OP for completeness.

**Edit 2:** As pointed out by saurabheights in the comments, you may need to run `find /home/<login> -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 775` a number of times until all the subdirectories are accessible.

Comment: Note in particular that ssh will refuse to run if the private keys in `~/.ssh/` are group- or world-readable.

Comment: For large amounts of files or directories, xargs will not work and the `-exec` flag of the `find` command may have to be used instead:  

`find /home/<login> -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;`  

`find /home/<login> -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;`

Also, note that the order there is to fix directory permissions *first* so the files within those directories can have their permissions fixed.

Comment: Minor thing: If directory is inaccessible, run `find /home/<login> -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 775` first and run it again and again till all subdirectories are fixed. Then run for files.

Answer (score 1):

In directory `/etc/skel` there is template of home directory. You can try to restore permissions to basic folders according to folders in /etc/skel.

In the future use rsync/cp/scp with -p switch to preserve permissions.

Comment: To be more specific, I used grsync, and I always ticked the boxes for preserving owner, permissions, etc. I don't know how they got all screwed up.